# Are there any truly EU-level political parties?

Tags: parties, european-union

In the European Parliament, parties operate as groups of national parties, see e.g. [current europarties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_political_party#Current_Europarties). They don't take members and don't operate in countries where they don't have any membership party. They're rather organisational vehicles for parliamentary work than true parties.

Are there any truly EU-level political parties? By truly EU-level, I mean that they operate on EU-level in a way analogous to how traditional parties operate on a national level. For example, aiming to operate everywhere in the EU, allowing membership from anyone in the EU, and encouraging members anywhere in the EU to start local sections (at local, regional, or national sections).

The list linked above only includes parties currently represented in the European Parliament. I know that no party according to my criteria currently has any representation, but are there any that are presently without representation?

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't the answer to your question obvious? You've linked to a list of all existing europarties, and you've already mentioned that none satisfies your criteria. Is what you have in mind something like the [Pan-European political organisations that are not Europarties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_political_party#Pan-European_political_organisations_that_are_not_Europarties) list?

Comment: Maybe they're not *recognised europarties* because they won't be represented in the European Parliament at the moment.

Comment: I edited my comment, is the other list I linked to closer to what you have in mind?

Comment: Ah, perhaps. It'd certainly be worth studying those more in detail to see if they meet my criteria.

Comment: There are negotiations to build an European Pirate Party, just meeting your criteria, but they are going on really slowly afaik.

Comment: @Lohoris - heh... telling thing about EU if the only thing they can agree on is benefits of piracy :)  ARRRRR.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly none that campaign on a Europe wide basis, or that have significant cross border representation.

This is only natural as there is no european demos to speak of.

Answer (score 3):

[Volt](https://www.volteuropa.org/about) would probably apply. They're a pan European party that's "neither right nor left". They accept members from every European country (and apparently Kenya, I'm not sure what's up with that).

They took part in the local elections in Belgium in October 2018 where they had lists in at least [Antwerp](https://stampmedia.be/index.php/artikel/volt-en-piratenpartij-samen-op-lijst-voor-antwerpse-verkiezingen) (they formed a kartel with the Pirate Party) and [Brussels](https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl/2018/07/29/partij-volt-komt-ook-bij-ons-met-lijst-bij-gemeenteraadsverkiezi/), so they try to be active. They didn't win any seats in that election although they came surprisingly close in Etterbeek.

They are also active in at least [Denmark](https://www.volteuropa.org/aarhus_gets_a_new_international_political_party) with the apparent intention of running in the EU parliament election in 2019.

Comment: They are active in Germany as well. They did however fail to meet our arbitrary 5% Hurdle to get any seats